# "Requests from referer https://www.googleapis.com/ are blocked" error

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm Brazilian, and I'm starting to make a sports blog. I went to PageSpeed ​​Insights to make an assessment of what I still need to adjust, but the analysis stops at 50% with the following error:

"Requests from referer https://www.googleapis.com/ are blocked"

What may be the problem? Would it be something simple to solve?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The main reason people get this issue is that they have a firewall / anti-virus blocking certain requests.

If you are using Brave Browser with 'Shields Up' then this is likely the cause of this issue.

Try using Google Chrome, in Incognito Mode, tethered to your mobile phone instead of Wifi / wired connection and see if the problem persists.

If it doesn't then use your normal browser and examine your requests and see if any headers etc. are being blocked.