# PageSpeed Insights times out

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I have several websites hosted on the same provider.  No matter what site I try, I get a "timed out" error on the Google PageSpeed Insights site (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) when I enter any of my site URLs.  It doesn't matter how large or how small the website is.

What I do is this: I enter my site's URL into Google's Page Insights "***Enter a web page URL***" textbox and click, "***Analyze***." The status bar reaches about 81% before I get the following error:.

"**Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)**"

When I look at Chrome's developer tools, it yields the following information about the script Google is using and where it is failing on their site:

[PageSpeed 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMP5T.jpg)

If I drill down to the URL of the API being used on Google's site, it is calling the **runPagespeed** method and returning a 403 error:

```js
/*
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [{
      "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
*/
```

I'm lost as to why Google is returning a 403 error.  I see nothing on my site's logs that indicates it's hitting a 403 error, so I can only assume the 403 error is on Google's end, or Lighthouse.  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Your API key is either wrong or you have restrictions on your API key.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't my API. The error is being generated by Google's PageSpeed Insights site, not my own.  I'm not using an API on any of my sites.  I'm simply going to: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/  and typing in my site's URL to have it generate a Page Speed report.  But instead, it generates an error and times out.

Comment: what is your site URL, let me check something

Comment: The error appears to be at your end, I can scan the site fine, do you happen to have any privacy plugins or firewall settings that might be interfering.

Comment: Ok, this is really weird. If I use the TOR browser, then all of my sites load fine on PageSpeed Insights. I'm at a loss. Before TOR, I'd tried five other standard browsers:  Chrome, Firefox, Firefox Developer edition, Edge and Brave. None of those worked. Two of those browser had plugins, but they were disabled. Is this an ISP issue? An Internet backbone provider issue? How would I go about pinpointing that? Is there a specific ISP firewall setting that is known to conflict with PageSpeed Insights?

Comment: To be fair I do not know, the only thing I can think of is that the referrer header is being completely stripped by your ISP or router. You often see a very similar issue with [brave browser with "shields up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508137/requests-from-referer-https-www-googleapis-com-are-blocked-error/59512854#59512854) - try following the general advice I give there about connecting to your phone on 4G and in incognito mode to rule out something on your device, if it still doesn't work that way it is device issue, if it does work then it is likely a firewall setting etc.

Comment: I never quite understood exactly what causes this issue as I have never been able to replicate it myself but given the error message and brave's behaviour that is my best guess.