# Page Speed Insights not showing any data

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OJrQ.png)

Attached picture showing what it displays when I put in the weblink of my website.

Would be great if someone could shed some light as to why it's not loading. It was working when I first started using page speed insights few months ago but recently started showing me these errors.

Comment: It works for me, could be related to this though (as they don't seem to show the error messages anymore) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508137/requests-from-referer-https-www-googleapis-com-are-blocked-error/59512854#59512854 - it scores 50 / 100 and main issues are "properly size images" (1.41s) followed by "reduce unused JavaScript" (0.9s)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried using my mobile hotspot with incognito mode on google chrome but that didn't solve my problem. It seems to work for some websites and not for others. Is there something on my website that is blocking this and is it possible to change it so I can make pagespeed analyze it properly?

Comment: I doubt it is something on your site as I can run the report from Page Speed Insights. It is even more confusing it would work for some sites and not for others, at that point I am afraid I am out of ideas. I would suggest trying https://web.dev/measure  and if that doesn't work use the lighthouse report in developer tools as they all provide the same info and use the same engine to power them!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that field data exists for the domain key. In case field data doesn't really exists, try lighthouse in built in chrome or use pagespeed-insights.com to do the lab data analysis and wait for field data to be accumulated.